# website development workflow for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, workflow

I am building a second Rails web-app from scratch. I am wonder what would be the best practice in terms of workflow:

- start coding basic functionalities, then add GUI design and repeat,
  or
- create full set of wireframes for basic functionalities, then
  design data and models, then code it up, then repeat

It seems to me that laying out wireframes forces me to think harder about how users will use the app, but choosing work-flow kinda depends on framework (support agile development or not).

What is your approach and what're pros and cons?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "best"; it depends on what's actually happening.

You may know *some* basic functionality before beginning workflow design, but it's unlikely you'll know all of it. Either way, high-level behavioral tests are a good place to start defining functionality at both the UX and lower levels.

I'm not sure what you mean by "support agile development or not", that doesn't have anything to do with the framework. The framework shouldn't have an impact on workflow, either, only on how the workflow is implemented.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am a newbie in web development. I thought a framework that takes less time to refactor would require less design in advance. I guess my question is this: should I create a set of wireframes to get a big picture of the app first, then write code to implement it, or start with models, write code and then change UI latter.